# Tensorflow support for python 3.6

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, visual-studio-2017, python-3.6

Do anyone know whether tensorflow support for python 3.6 have come or not ? If not then please share if you have any idea when it will come . 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Yes, Tensorflow support for Python 3.6, you can download here  

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow

then just type  
pip install C:\Users\yourcomputername\Downloads\tensorflow-1.3.0rc2-cp36-
cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried your method but but there is exception appeared on cmd. Screenshot is below - 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNYUL.png

Comment: have you downloaded the .whl file?  in the above link?

Comment: yes I did . The error message shows after running the command above.

Comment: Oh, the issue is solved. Just ran the same command on cmd administrator mode then it worked. Just missed this simple and silly thing. 

From now on, I will emphasize about running on administrator mode when installing something using cmd.  Had a good lesson there ! lol ...  

Thanks for the help once again.

Comment: Now facing a new issue integrating tensorflow in vs2017. I can run the code of tensorflow in cmd but couldn't run it on vs.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the installation documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux). You can install tensorflow for `Python 3.n` as follows:

> Issue one of the following commands to install TensorFlow in the
>   active virtualenv environment:

```
(tensorflow)$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow     # for Python 3.n 
(tensorflow)$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu # for Python 3.n and GPU
```